# Как правильно создать тест с использованием Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mock

У меня есть метод который нужно протестировать и создать заглушку для внешней зависимости в тесте.
Я только начинаю знакомится с Mockito и возникают трудности с реализацией.

Вот мой клас с методом.

public class SomeClass  {

```
private AnotherClass another;

public SomeClass(AnotherClass another) {
    this.another = another;
}


public String reverse(String string) {
    StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner("");
    for (String word : string.split("(?= )")) {
        stringJoiner.add(another.reverse(word));
    }
    return  stringJoiner.toString();
}
```

}

Вот что я пытаюсь сделать:

class SomeClassTest {

```
private AnotherClass anotherMock = mock(AnotherClass.class);

private SomeClass someClass;

@Test
void reverse_shouldDoSomething() {
    when(anotherMock.reverse("abc")).thenReturn("cba");
    when(anotherMock.reverse(" ")).thenReturn(" ");
    someClass = new SomeClass(anotherMock);
    String actual = someClass.reverse("abc    ");
    String expected = "cba    ";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Видимо эта реализация неверная. Может кто-то знает как правильно сделать тест, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: что это значит `split("(?= )")`?

Comment: через split("(?= )" функция разделяет строку по пробелу, при этом сохраняя все пробелы и каждое отдельно слово реверсует  через функцию another.reverse(word), потом все слова соединяет

Comment: Вы описали 2 сценария для входных данных ("abc" и " "), а тестируете третий, которого нет в описании `when(...)`. И вообще, для каждого кейса должен быть свой тест!

Comment: да, в этом и мой вопрос. Эти сценарии это части строки, которая разделяется сплитом. Метод который вызывается у mock обьекта,  реверсит каждую часть, поэтому так как строка состоит из многих подстрок, для каждой подстроки свой сценарий.  Тестируемый метод должен сравнить входящую строку  со строкой, которая соединяет перевернутые подстроки.  Но как правильно реализовать сам метод я не знаю.